# Service workers - testing on mobile with ngrok

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, ngrok

I'm incorporating `service workers` into my `meteor` app; everything works fine on desktop browsers so I'm trying to test it out on mobiles.

So the app is running on `localhost` and I'm running `ngrok` so I can access on my phone. When the code tries to install the `service worker`, I get the following error:

`SecurityError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: the origin of the provided scriptURL (localhost:3000) does not match the current origin (https://abc123.ngrok.io)`

Is there any way around this so I can play with `service workers` on my phone during development?

(Here is my setup in case it makes a difference - it's pretty standard)

```
try {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(Meteor.absoluteUrl('sw.js')).then((registration) => {
          return registration.pushManager.getSubscription()
          .then((subscription) => {
            if(subscription) {
              return subscription;
            }
            const reg = registration.pushManager.subscribe({
              userVisibleOnly: true,
              applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array(publicKey)
            });
            return reg;
          })
          .then((subscription) => {
            savePushRegistration.call({ pushSubscription: JSON.stringify(subscription) });
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.info('Can\'t load SW', error); //This is where the error appears
        });
      } catch (e) {
        // We're good here
        // Just an old browser
      }
    });
```

Comment: Obviously one solution would be to just hardcode the `ngrok` url at the point of registration - `navigator.serviceWorker.register("abc123.ngrok.io")` - which is what I'm doing now; but this is very inefficient and time-consuming

Comment: You may refer with this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers). It stated that service workers are restricted to running across HTTPS for security reasons. GitHub is therefore a good place to host experiments, as it supports HTTPS. In order to facilitate local development, localhost is considered a secure origin by browsers as well. You may check this [Security considerations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the link @abielita, but my issue is that I'm using `ngrok` to expose my `localhost` to the web so I can access it on a mobile / other computers. The problem is that the origin of the service worker is `localhost` which doesn't match the page url (`https://abc123.ngrok.io`). 

Basically I want to play around on different desktops and mobiles without actually deploying the app

Comment: Have you tried setting the ROOT_URL environment variable for Meteor?

Comment: Instead of using `Meteor.absoluteUrl('sw.js')`, you can just use `${location.origin}/sw.js`
Assuming it's served at that url. 
If the url is always changing, you can just replace `Meteor.absoluteUrl('sw.js').replace('localhost', location.origin)`

Comment: I've moved on but hopefully @Norfeldt will see this, as they're the one who put the bounty on

Answer (score 3):

I run HTTPS web servers on my laptop that my devices can connect to if they're on the same WiFi network.  I configure custom CNAMEs with short TTL (5 minutes) for my domain and provide my laptop's IPs for them.  My laptop server listens for those hostnames:

https://laptop-home.example.com
https://laptop-work.example.com
https://laptop-secret-lair.example.com

Getting HTTPs running locally on your computer is beyond the scope of this question, but you should create your own self-signed certificates using a custom CA Root certificate that you can install and trust on your phone.  Then, you'll avoid SSL warnings when browsing to all of your self-signed sites.

A little more work than using a remote server, but well worth it if you want to avoid outside servers.